# How to convert string to code in vb.net and to view static or public variables of main project

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, compiler-construction, vbcodeprovider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to expose current assembly to CodeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860742/how-to-expose-current-assembly-to-codeprovider)

I wrote a code which converts a string from a textbox in vb.net like in this exemple: [how to convert string to code in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825107/how-to-convert-string-to-code-in-c-sharp)

But In this class I can't call any static variables and methods from main project. 
That is code vb.net:

```
Dim vb As New VBCodeProvider()
Dim icc As ICodeCompiler = vb.CreateCompiler()
cp = New CompilerParameters
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Comatic(de-ch).exe")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll")
cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
cp.GenerateInMemory = True
Dim sb As New StringBuilder("")

sb.Append("Imports System" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Imports System.Windows.Forms" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Imports System.Xml" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Imports Comatic" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Imports System.Data" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("<System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(False)> _" & vbNewLine)

sb.Append("Public Class VbCodeEvaler" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Public Sub EvalCode()" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append(TxVbCode.Text & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("End Sub" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.EvalCode)" & vbNewLine) 'System.Threading.
sb.Append("Public Sub StartThred()" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("t.Start()" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("End Sub" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("Public Sub StopThred()" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("t.Abort()" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("End Sub" & vbNewLine)
sb.Append("End Class" & vbNewLine)

cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString())
If cr.Errors.Count > 0 Then
  MsgBox("Error: " & cr.Errors(0).ErrorText)
  Return Null
End If

Dim a As System.Reflection.Assembly = cr.CompiledAssembly
Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance("VbCodeEvaler")
Dim t As Type = o.GetType()
'Dim mi As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("EvalCode")
Dim mi As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("StartThred")
mi.Invoke(o, Null)
```

How I can call all static and public methods and variables from main project?
Thanks!

Comment: An almost identical question to the one I asked earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860742/how-to-expose-current-assembly-to-codeprovider

Comment: OK, but he doesn't have any answers...

Comment: ('He' - Is me!) I am just linking to it for reference. Which ever one receives an accepted answer first should be kept open and the other closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are calling a static method in a module you need to explicitly define the module as public. Change:

```
Module Module1
```

to

```
Public Module Module1
```

You should be able to access any shared members of classes already