# How to convert String into code in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

First, let's have a look at my code:

```
Private Sub FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    txtMDF.Text = My.Settings.MDF

End Sub
```

Assume `My.Settings.MDF` has a string value of `Application.StartupPath + "\MyDB.mdf"`. I get this result:

[image: Image 1]

> But I want the result to be:

[image: Image 2]

I have tried the following links and methods:

- [How to convert string to code in vb.net and to view static or public variables of main project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862600/how-to-convert-string-to-code-in-vb-net-and-to-view-static-or-public-variables-o)
- CodeDom - But didn't understand it.

Comment: Why put `Application.StartupPath` into the setting? just leave in the name of your file in the setting and then use `Path.Combine()` to get the full filename

Comment: No, I want it just like at first open the file location to be Application.StartupPath + + "\MyDB.mdf" but later if I want to change the Database location it should be changed and save in My.Settings...

Comment: So present them with the default, and then if they want to change the location you'll have to save their entire filepath specifically.

Comment: But Can't I do what I asked?

Comment: Nope not directly... If you REALLY need a variable prefix like that I suggest you store it as something like "!SUP\MuDB.mdf" then do a replace when you read it.

Comment: As already mentioned a few times, it can't be done. You need to save their specific path separately and later retrieve it for use as @Trevor has mentioned and Pro Grammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ProGamer Suggested,

**First**

> *save you `My.Settings.MDF` String = None*

**Second**

> Edit your code as follows:

```
Private Sub FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If My.Settings.MDF = "None" Then
        txtMDF.Text = Application.StartupPath + "\MyDB.mdf"
    Else
        txtMDF.Text = My.Settings.MDF
    End If
    txtMDF.Text = My.Settings.MDF

End Sub
```

**Third**

> Add the following code to YourFormClose_Event

```
Private Sub FormClosing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    My.Settings.MDF = txtMDF.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

> And NOTE that you should select "User" from 'Scope Drop Down' in the Settings for MDF instead of "Application" or else My.Settings.Save() will not work and it will remain "None"

Example:

[image]

Comment: My Pleasure! And waiting for your result. :) ;)

Comment: `If ... else` statement in `FormLoad` have no sense, because you overwrite `txtMDF.Text` anyway by value from settings

Comment: @Fabio is correct.  The last line of your code will overwrite the value in txtMDF.Text with the value of "None" since the value in My.Settings.MDF still contains the value "None" and has not yet been saved with the new value.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I added that because suppose he use that location in his ConnectionString and he open the Connection on Form_Load then he would get error so I added that and it would not affect because I think it will only do that when he first launch it later once he changed the value in My.Settings.MDF then it will be just ok....
I want to know if I am correct please let me know.... tnx!

Comment: Thank you guys for all of your help but I don't have any issue till now using Mohammad Zulfikar's code...